# Why does Ctrl-D open Mission Control?

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard, mojave

When I try to use Ctrl-D in Terminal for EOF, it doesn't work.  Instead it starts Mission Control, moving all my windows around.  I have checked under System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts and Ctrl-D is not defined as a shortcut there.  Mission Control is the default Ctrl up arrow.  So why is this happening and how can I make Ctrl-D function as EOF character instead?

I'm running Mojave 10.14.4

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doh!  It turns out there was a custom keyboard shortcut defined in BetterTouchTool.  Problem solved.